# Prefs not Working

Tags: java, android

I was recently making a few variables and prefs. I was working on another thing more than just the prefs, yet this is the very basics.  I found the root of my problem was in the preferences, so in the code listed below it shows the prefs.  I was wondering how to solve the problem because for some reason the prefs are not working. Please help. **I have been having this problem since 1 month.**--

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shop_main);
    this.context = getBaseContext();

    //Creating prefs
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.example.alreadyinthecodeandjustforshow",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Reading boolean nad int prefs
    locked1 = prefs.getBoolean(savelocked, false);
    locked2 = prefs.getBoolean(savelocked2, false);
    locked3 = prefs.getBoolean(savelocked3, false);
    locked4 = prefs.getBoolean(savelocked4, false);
    locked5 = prefs.getBoolean(savelocked5, false);
    buy1 = prefs.getInt(el, 0);
    buy2 = prefs.getInt(bl, 0);
    buy3 = prefs.getInt(dl, 0);
    buy4 = prefs.getInt(fl, 0);
    buy5 = prefs.getInt(gl, 0);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    prefs.edit().putBoolean(savelocked, locked1).apply();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(savelocked2, locked2).apply();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(savelocked3, locked3).apply();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(savelocked4, locked4).apply();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(savelocked5, locked5).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt(el, buy1).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt(bl, buy2).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt(dl, buy3).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt(fl, buy4).apply();
    prefs.edit().putInt(gl, buy5).apply();
}
```

Please help. I have been trying to solve this problem for **One month.**Thanks so much.

Comment: grammar may be improper sorry about that

Comment: @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(savelocked, locked1);
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(savelocked2, locked2);
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(savelocked3, locked3);
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(savelocked4, locked4);
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(savelocked5, locked5);
    prefsEditor.putInt(el, buy1);
    prefsEditor.putInt(bl, buy2);
    prefsEditor.putInt(dl, buy3);
    prefsEditor.putInt(fl, buy4);
    prefsEditor.putInt(gl, buy5);
    prefsEditor.commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will try that.

Comment: the comment is updated.

Comment: still no solution to the problem yet. I think there must be a problem with somewhere else in the code. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: do you have teamviewer ?

Comment: No, sorry. Thanks for all your help though.